# Speed up Postgres Query that has index but still slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, slow-log, query-performance

Have roughly 50 million rows in a table called 'messages'. The problem is even with indexes particular queries run very slow. My background is more Mysql so I'm more of a newb on Postgres (9.5). Any suggestion or help to solve an issue with slow queries on this table would be greatly appreciated.

The table is structured as so:

```
mydatabase=# \d+ messages


 id              | integer                     | not null default nextval('messages_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 conversation_id | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 user_id         | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 content         | text                        |                                                       | extended |              | 
 attached_photos | text                        |                                                       | extended |              | 
 attached_video  | text                        |                                                       | extended |              | 
 status          | character varying(255)      |                                                       | extended |              | 
 created_at      | timestamp without time zone | not null                                              | plain    |              | 
 updated_at      | timestamp without time zone | not null                                              | plain    |              | 
 attached_audio  | text                        |                                                       | extended |              | 
 sticker_url     | character varying(255)      |                                                       | extended |              | 
 link_preview    | text                        |                                                       | extended |              | 
 flash_duration  | integer                     |                                                       | plain    |              | 
 seen_by_users   | text                        |                                                       | extended |              |
```

Query that runs slow:

```
SELECT "messages"."conversation_id"
FROM "messages"
WHERE (conversation_id = ANY(VALUES (15934630),(15934629),(15388237),(15697209),(15603874),(14751993),(15890943),(15880199),(15879443),(15879306),(15876070),(15876042),(15875493),(15852879),(15854076),(15853094),(15853066),(15776120),(15822505),(15827053),(15825771),(15822703),(15815065),(15815064),(15814905),(15811289),(15810939),(15810612),(15805284),(15805228),(15805153),(15805134),(15805116),(15796019),(15778680),(15778072),(15777807),(12729195),(15776464),(15776346),(15742637),(15742453),(15742430),(15730704),(15730680),(15730657),(15730328),(15730269),(14329627),(15730067),(15696423),(15695231),(15694267),(15642766),(15642613),(15642185),(15639928),(15633679),(15639041),(15638589),(15637484),(15637159),(15637004),(15636666),(15636512),(15636105),(15635907),(15635904),(15635865),(15634535),(15634353),(15634051),(15633950),(15633729),(15633718),(15633717),(15633700),(15631640),(15631488),(15631381),(15626302),(15625106),(15624485),(15610936),(15607494),(15604215),(15584367),(15572160),(15570679),(15570676),(15570206),(12232522),(14667668),(13432845),(15483195),(15495098),(15495074),(15495021),(15493690),(14920768),(15493127),(15450633),(15489768),(15488477),(15369921),(15484085),(15484012),(15483592),(15483013),(15482860),(15480941),(14329487),(15480225),(15479749),(15479620),(15477145),(13125614),(15467384),(15466078),(15457849),(15457537),(15451960),(15451916),(15451514),(15451246),(15369933),(15415313),(15411874),(15409115),(15408841),(15408800),(15408759),(15407783),(15408436),(15408415),(15404173),(15403209),(15403005),(15400413),(15399503),(15397889),(15376730),(15359143),(15338970),(15338895),(15337117),(15337086),(15335616),(15334923),(15334919),(14378778),(15325036),(15324988),(15124191),(15128102),(15285947),(15285191),(15284414),(15273629),(15200349),(15259769),(15259551),(15258768),(15258713),(15258596),(15254160),(15253166),(15253050),(15252986),(15252967),(15252841),(15252812),(15251559),(15249675),(15240491),(15218039),(15216899),(15215945),(15200163),(15196650),(15181907),(15181842),(15179024),(15166390),(15128122),(15145083),(15128208),(15128013),(15067802),(15088189),(15088144),(15087957),(15085479),(15085366),(15084528),(15084405),(14954163),(15072062),(15059628),(15054129),(15048453),(15045099),(15044923),(15000883),(15000026),(14998606),(14997946),(14996351),(14996173),(14996027),(14991481),(14991227),(14984719),(14961598),(14958006),(14957439),(14926195),(14920672),(14955456),(14955116),(13125522),(14927203),(14926218),(14920835),(14920467),(14915928),(14915788),(14914655),(14913930),(14911082),(14910637),(14910605),(14899513),(14899428),(14833333),(14664544),(13503831),(14858618),(14842848),(14699540),(14836180),(14836022),(14835944),(14835701),(14835581),(14835443),(14544730),(14835196),(14835122),(14834435),(14834224),(14833501),(14826879),(14826763),(14824599),(14822811),(14822516),(14737945),(14703402),(14551870),(14732063),(14731876),(14392495),(14664755),(14664685),(14664180),(14664089),(13320381),(14586124),(14572448),(14547665),(13891755),(14549805),(14532398),(14544136),(14545391),(14545608),(14536433),(14383187),(14391606),(14502029),(14502023),(14501947),(14493390),(14493301),(14493133),(14493106),(14492417),(14491811),(14483838),(14478737),(14451326),(14422841),(14422735),(14382190),(14396364),(14385796),(14095371),(14340527),(14340348),(14340219),(14340112),(14339719),(14339637),(14339260),(14329885),(14338519),(14338422),(14337829),(14337815),(14330749),(14329975),(14329862),(14255005),(14290960),(14290061),(14289829),(14267843),(14260179),(14259717),(14259150),(14254891),(14254742),(14250150),(14246119),(14170540),(14169335),(14153092),(14127653),(14095396),(14095250),(14084943),(14084820),(14084632),(14002977),(13971264),(13924115),(13962418),(13946815),(13885515),(13938702),(13930166),(13924001),(12868949),(13857244),(13854344),(13851229),(13850583),(13850266),(13850242),(13848473),(13846377),(13846290),(13845519),(13844800),(13844515),(13841217),(13841116),(13818979),(13812047),(13745025),(13771881),(13730839),(13730753),(13755010),(13745357),(13616479),(11115494),(13771887),(13772141),(13767798),(13767481),(13766011),(12955679),(13764449),(13764193),(13763360),(13763129),(13762802),(13730658),(13754911),(13750076),(13747022),(13605081),(13731178),(13731053),(13730535),(13729175),(13679180),(13672842),(13619741),(13616778),(13596378),(13594848),(13573024),(13572587),(13503828),(13569622),(13566462),(13539530),(13538755),(13538744),(13538702),(13537867),(13463277),(13462487),(13462441),(13400950),(12150232),(15406219),(15405115),(15404609),(15404277),(15403952),(13400266),(13141154),(13395428),(13395348),(13394882),(13392328),(13059939),(13319958),(13319359),(13318057),(13316952),(13304692),(13302824),(13297772),(13296130),(12464767),(13243518),(13227681),(12729282),(13202620),(13169646),(13169606),(13168852),(13164923),(13164779),(13164490),(13161841),(13125504),(12949551),(12949307),(12948032),(12947962),(12947961),(12946338),(12916871),(12944652),(12941995),(12929827),(12928444),(12928163),(12927973),(12925595),(12923666),(12913373),(12883972),(12883936),(12880086),(12855282),(12878088),(12875454),(12869400),(12857036),(12854557),(12850866),(12848871),(12847938),(12836655),(12812434),(12811888),(12811651),(12811473),(12808640),(12808419),(12805810),(12804053),(12803487),(12803469),(12803267),(12803210),(12803195),(12803123),(12800264),(12800215),(12790740),(12790008),(12770772),(12768071),(12737401),(12730336),(12728839),(12728891),(12728847),(12727378),(12727033),(12706859),(12534533),(12073350),(12667092),(12667262),(12667229),(12593195),(12581381),(12565104),(12138402),(12547076),(12546920),(12446448),(12367921),(12536222),(12534934),(12536069),(12464463),(12518023),(12512795),(12442622),(12511810),(12207236),(12501848),(12501760),(12500739),(12500673),(12497218),(12483284),(12380519),(12466163),(12466131),(12464768),(12464678),(12464492),(12462413),(12446538),(12446446),(12371253),(12073620),(12413051),(12375585),(12373154),(12373103),(11806939),(12371331),(12369821),(12368064),(12366314),(12366212),(12366004),(12345825),(12304641),(12304078),(12302783),(12301802),(12300752),(12300520),(12298851),(12298856),(12298797),(12233342),(12233068),(12231183),(12231718),(12151550),(12229799),(12208112),(12202481),(14493237),(14456540),(14430533),(14420452),(14395868),(12185055),(12153267),(12151935),(12151661),(12150624),(12147132),(12147087),(12143727),(12143492),(12142184),(12138967),(12138657),(12133663),(12035312),(12111365),(12083546),(12109596),(12083223),(12103250),(12083378),(12080701),(12075888),(12075289),(12075241),(12073258),(12073208),(12031591),(11585564),(12011010),(12005374),(12005338),(12004465),(12003223),(12003295),(11996266),(11996147),(11987535),(11985077),(11982299),(11978407),(11978342),(11977292),(11976108),(11066836),(11946374),(11946031),(11945634),(11944404),(11944169),(11942606),(11942489),(11942305),(11905587),(11896253),(11887108),(11871238),(11873035),(11871510),(11868219),(11867127),(11862701),(11809112),(11855806),(11852184),(11852175),(11795125),(11841765),(11841520),(11840812),(11831682),(11836044),(11836159),(11809581),(11809137),(11808423),(11808310),(11807173),(11806578),(11803644),(11800350),(11799318),(11794270),(11793982),(11793046),(11385987),(11784903),(11773013),(11773007),(11771639),(11762317),(11736124),(11736101),(11736082),(11736017),(11735789),(11735146),(11732627),(11729770),(11729741),(11725598),(11718321),(11717807),(11717220),(11716867),(11715185),(11427784),(11662425),(11372661),(11615757),(11557096),(11587776),(11587619),(11586873),(11586834),(11586647),(11586326),(11585973),(11585383),(11585176),(11558812),(11558528),(11557459),(11557335),(11548694),(11519450),(11519140),(11518994),(11516933),(11504170),(11503384),(11501616),(11489039),(11483558),(11470810),(11458873),(11458281),(11458188),(11457353),(11455530),(11454908),(11450763),(11450270),(11450265),(11443773),(11441628),(11441278),(11434994),(11429437),(11428812),(11420895),(11419688),(13105977),(13105336),(13105335),(13100834),(13098876),(13092420),(13092289),(13090441),(13074242),(12805690),(13044996),(13060085),(13050326),(13027069),(13026682),(13024915),(13020903),(13020628),(13020503),(13017760),(13016023),(13012472),(12926880),(12761218),(12970924),(12955914),(12955238),(12949617),(11419574),(11408296),(11392577),(11390568),(11389397),(11386728),(11372589),(11382045),(11381216),(11381166),(11377944),(11377730),(11377675),(11375338),(11374411),(11372780),(11372764),(11364843),(11364687),(11363832),(11363687),(11219899),(11224152),(11228170),(11230543),(11230421),(11235524),(11237628),(11039570),(11250102),(11250007),(11249941),(11250039),(11250990),(11252859),(11252698),(11255942),(11258274),(11259964),(11260158),(11261068),(11261997),(11263141),(11263374),(11038946),(11040171),(11040303),(11040368),(11040819),(11040635),(11040794),(11041140),(11041119),(11041169),(11041261),(11041597),(11041840),(11041919),(11042238),(11044648),(11049744),(11289961),(11296758),(11040310),(11065953),(11040530),(11066176),(11066475),(11066616),(11066687),(11066968),(11067656),(11068015),(11068296),(11067117),(11068502),(11073105),(11072974),(11066323),(11073725),(11074181),(11073887),(11075345),(11076177),(11078964),(11079912),(11084928),(11087778),(11039361),(11089084),(11299320),(11036144),(11093741),(11098103),(11295667),(11106717),(11106827),(11109834),(11110136),(11110930),(11322598),(11111280),(11322605),(11041358),(11111804),(11112613),(11112565),(11326319),(11113070),(11326484),(11326366),(11326619),(11326643),(11326666),(11327048),(11113786),(11329459),(11332130),(11333713),(11332441),(11333003),(11333272),(11334579),(11336031),(11335364),(11336467),(11336545),(11128981),(11136640),(11138821),(11139903),(11151937),(11112995),(11152470),(11162384),(11170785),(11174996),(11175241),(11174976),(11176703),(11176552),(11176966),(11177172),(11067092),(11209385),(11209705),(11210160),(11211825)))
AND "messages"."status" = $1;
```

Indexes on table:

```
messages   | index_messages_on_conversation_id             | conversation_id
messages   | index_messages_on_conversation_id_status      | status, conversation_id
messages   | index_messages_on_created_at                  | created_at
messages   | index_messages_on_seen_by_users               | seen_by_users
messages   | index_messages_on_user_id                     | user_id
messages   | index_messages_on_user_id_and_conversation_id | user_id, conversation_id
messages   | messages_pkey                                 | id
```

Output of running explain on slow query:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=12.09..1096.79 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=6562.604..6562.604 rows=0 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=2377 read=697
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=11.52..13.52 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=0.440..0.995 rows=768 loops=1)
         Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1
     ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..9.60 rows=768 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.177 rows=768 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using index_messages_on_conversation_id_status on messages  (cost=0.57..5.41 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=8.543..8.543 rows=0 loops=768)
         Index Cond: ((conversation_id = "*VALUES*".column1) AND (status = '1'::text))
         Heap Fetches: 0
         Buffers: shared hit=2377 read=697
 Planning time: 0.654 ms
 Execution time: 6562.663 ms
```

Index result.

```
 Schema | Name | Type | Owner | Table | Size | Description
--------+------------------------------------------+-------+‌​-------+----------+-‌​--------+-----------‌​--
 public | index_messages_on_conversation_id_status | index | jsh | messages | 6636 MB | 
(1 row)
```

Comment: This query returns 0 rows. Have you tried rewriting = ANY(VALUES) into `IN ()`

Comment: will find a more recent query

Comment: Can you paste the output of `\di+ index_messages_on_conversation_id_status`

Comment: @EvanCarroll - Here is the output:                                          List of relations
 Schema |                   Name                   | Type  | Owner |  Table   |  Size   | Description 
--------+------------------------------------------+-------+-------+----------+---------+-------------
 public | index_messages_on_conversation_id_status | index | jsh   | messages | 6636 MB | 
(1 row)

Comment: @Ranknoodie that's why as I suspected in my answer. You need to run `VACUUM FULL messages` and rewrite that table and index. then run the same command and paste again. Your index is 6x the size of mine.

Comment: Also in the future always put your edits (additional information) into the question.

Answer (score 5):

## Emulating your setup

I think your index is badly maintained. That's about all I can come up with. I tried and emulated everything with 50 M rows.

```
CREATE TABLE messages
AS
  SELECT
    x::int AS conversation_id,
    ((x::int%26)+97)::"char" AS status
  FROM generate_series(1,50e6) AS gs(x);

CREATE INDEX ON messages (conversation_id , status);

ANALYZE messages;
```

From there, the only modification I made was to change your placeholder to 'a'.. IE,

```
AND "messages"."status" = $1;
```

to this,

```
AND "messages"."status" = 'a';
```

You can see the query plan here, the very same.

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=14.05..1734.48 rows=955000 width=4) (actual time=0.755..6.384 rows=31 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=13.49..15.49 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=0.689..1.007 rows=899 loops=1)
         Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1
         ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..11.24 rows=899 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.282 rows=899 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using messages_conversation_id_status_idx on messages  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=899)
         Index Cond: ((conversation_id = "*VALUES*".column1) AND (status = 'a'::"char"))
         Heap Fetches: 31
 Planning time: 1.197 ms
 Execution time: 6.463 ms
(9 rows)
```

My assumption is that you either

1. have lots of dead rows, or a badly maintained index.
2. have a taxed out CPU, or taxed out ram.

For reference, my whole index is `1071 MB` which fits into memory. If you can't fit it into memory you may be slightly slower but even if you have to page the index you can not account for that kind of slow down unless you have major IO bottlenecks -- it's only 1 GB.

## Solution

Try `VACUUM FULL messages`.

## Alternative plan

As I suggested in the comments too rewriting to an IN statement provides a slightly faster plan. If that saves you here, I think it's more luck though. I think you've got other problems.

```
    QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using messages_conversation_id_status_idx on messages  (cost=0.56..4170.53 rows=36 width=4) (actual time=0.252..4.503 rows=31 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((conversation_id = ANY ('{15934630,15934629,15388237,15697209,15603874,14751993,15890943,15880199,15879443,15879306,15876070,15876042,15875493,15852879,15854076,15853094,15853066,15776120,15822505,15827053,15825771,15822703,15815065,15815064,15814905,15811289,15810939,15810612,15805284,15805228,15805153,15805134,15805116,15796019,15778680,15778072,15777807,12729195,15776464,15776346,15742637,15742453,15742430,15730704,15730680,15730657,15730328,15730269,14329627,15730067,15696423,15695231,15694267,15642766,15642613,15642185,15639928,15633679,15639041,15638589,15637484,15637159,15637004,15636666,15636512,15636105,15635907,15635904,15635865,15634535,15634353,15634051,15633950,15633729,15633718,15633717,15633700,15631640,15631488,15631381,15626302,15625106,15624485,15610936,15607494,15604215,15584367,15572160,15570679,15570676,15570206,12232522,14667668,13432845,15483195,15495098,15495074,15495021,15493690,14920768,15493127,15450633,15489768,15488477,15369921,15484085,15484012,15483592,15483013,15482860,15480941,14329487,15480225,15479749,15479620,15477145,13125614,15467384,15466078,15457849,15457537,15451960,15451916,15451514,15451246,15369933,15415313,15411874,15409115,15408841,15408800,15408759,15407783,15408436,15408415,15404173,15403209,15403005,15400413,15399503,15397889,15376730,15359143,15338970,15338895,15337117,15337086,15335616,15334923,15334919,14378778,15325036,15324988,15124191,15128102,15285947,15285191,15284414,15273629,15200349,15259769,15259551,15258768,15258713,15258596,15254160,15253166,15253050,15252986,15252967,15252841,15252812,15251559,15249675,15240491,15218039,15216899,15215945,15200163,15196650,15181907,15181842,15179024,15166390,15128122,15145083,15128208,15128013,15067802,15088189,15088144,15087957,15085479,15085366,15084528,15084405,14954163,15072062,15059628,15054129,15048453,15045099,15044923,15000883,15000026,14998606,14997946,14996351,14996173,14996027,14991481,14991227,14984719,14961598,14958006,14957439,14926195,14920672,14955456,14955116,13125522,14927203,14926218,14920835,14920467,14915928,14915788,14914655,14913930,14911082,14910637,14910605,14899513,14899428,14833333,14664544,13503831,14858618,14842848,14699540,14836180,14836022,14835944,14835701,14835581,14835443,14544730,14835196,14835122,14834435,14834224,14833501,14826879,14826763,14824599,14822811,14822516,14737945,14703402,14551870,14732063,14731876,14392495,14664755,14664685,14664180,14664089,13320381,14586124,14572448,14547665,13891755,14549805,14532398,14544136,14545391,14545608,14536433,14383187,14391606,14502029,14502023,14501947,14493390,14493301,14493133,14493106,14492417,14491811,14483838,14478737,14451326,14422841,14422735,14382190,14396364,14385796,14095371,14340527,14340348,14340219,14340112,14339719,14339637,14339260,14329885,14338519,14338422,14337829,14337815,14330749,14329975,14329862,14255005,14290960,14290061,14289829,14267843,14260179,14259717,14259150,14254891,14254742,14250150,14246119,14170540,14169335,14153092,14127653,14095396,14095250,14084943,14084820,14084632,14002977,13971264,13924115,13962418,13946815,13885515,13938702,13930166,13924001,12868949,13857244,13854344,13851229,13850583,13850266,13850242,13848473,13846377,13846290,13845519,13844800,13844515,13841217,13841116,13818979,13812047,13745025,13771881,13730839,13730753,13755010,13745357,13616479,11115494,13771887,13772141,13767798,13767481,13766011,12955679,13764449,13764193,13763360,13763129,13762802,13730658,13754911,13750076,13747022,13605081,13731178,13731053,13730535,13729175,13679180,13672842,13619741,13616778,13596378,13594848,13573024,13572587,13503828,13569622,13566462,13539530,13538755,13538744,13538702,13537867,13463277,13462487,13462441,13400950,12150232,15406219,15405115,15404609,15404277,15403952,13400266,13141154,13395428,13395348,13394882,13392328,13059939,13319958,13319359,13318057,13316952,13304692,13302824,13297772,13296130,12464767,13243518,13227681,12729282,13202620,13169646,13169606,13168852,13164923,13164779,13164490,13161841,13125504,12949551,12949307,12948032,12947962,12947961,12946338,12916871,12944652,12941995,12929827,12928444,12928163,12927973,12925595,12923666,12913373,12883972,12883936,12880086,12855282,12878088,12875454,12869400,12857036,12854557,12850866,12848871,12847938,12836655,12812434,12811888,12811651,12811473,12808640,12808419,12805810,12804053,12803487,12803469,12803267,12803210,12803195,12803123,12800264,12800215,12790740,12790008,12770772,12768071,12737401,12730336,12728839,12728891,12728847,12727378,12727033,12706859,12534533,12073350,12667092,12667262,12667229,12593195,12581381,12565104,12138402,12547076,12546920,12446448,12367921,12536222,12534934,12536069,12464463,12518023,12512795,12442622,12511810,12207236,12501848,12501760,12500739,12500673,12497218,12483284,12380519,12466163,12466131,12464768,12464678,12464492,12462413,12446538,12446446,12371253,12073620,12413051,12375585,12373154,12373103,11806939,12371331,12369821,12368064,12366314,12366212,12366004,12345825,12304641,12304078,12302783,12301802,12300752,12300520,12298851,12298856,12298797,12233342,12233068,12231183,12231718,12151550,12229799,12208112,12202481,14493237,14456540,14430533,14420452,14395868,12185055,12153267,12151935,12151661,12150624,12147132,12147087,12143727,12143492,12142184,12138967,12138657,12133663,12035312,12111365,12083546,12109596,12083223,12103250,12083378,12080701,12075888,12075289,12075241,12073258,12073208,12031591,11585564,12011010,12005374,12005338,12004465,12003223,12003295,11996266,11996147,11987535,11985077,11982299,11978407,11978342,11977292,11976108,11066836,11946374,11946031,11945634,11944404,11944169,11942606,11942489,11942305,11905587,11896253,11887108,11871238,11873035,11871510,11868219,11867127,11862701,11809112,11855806,11852184,11852175,11795125,11841765,11841520,11840812,11831682,11836044,11836159,11809581,11809137,11808423,11808310,11807173,11806578,11803644,11800350,11799318,11794270,11793982,11793046,11385987,11784903,11773013,11773007,11771639,11762317,11736124,11736101,11736082,11736017,11735789,11735146,11732627,11729770,11729741,11725598,11718321,11717807,11717220,11716867,11715185,11427784,11662425,11372661,11615757,11557096,11587776,11587619,11586873,11586834,11586647,11586326,11585973,11585383,11585176,11558812,11558528,11557459,11557335,11548694,11519450,11519140,11518994,11516933,11504170,11503384,11501616,11489039,11483558,11470810,11458873,11458281,11458188,11457353,11455530,11454908,11450763,11450270,11450265,11443773,11441628,11441278,11434994,11429437,11428812,11420895,11419688,13105977,13105336,13105335,13100834,13098876,13092420,13092289,13090441,13074242,12805690,13044996,13060085,13050326,13027069,13026682,13024915,13020903,13020628,13020503,13017760,13016023,13012472,12926880,12761218,12970924,12955914,12955238,12949617,11419574,11408296,11392577,11390568,11389397,11386728,11372589,11382045,11381216,11381166,11377944,11377730,11377675,11375338,11374411,11372780,11372764,11364843,11364687,11363832,11363687,11219899,11224152,11228170,11230543,11230421,11235524,11237628,11039570,11250102,11250007,11249941,11250039,11250990,11252859,11252698,11255942,11258274,11259964,11260158,11261068,11261997,11263141,11263374,11038946,11040171,11040303,11040368,11040819,11040635,11040794,11041140,11041119,11041169,11041261,11041597,11041840,11041919,11042238,11044648,11049744,11289961,11296758,11040310,11065953,11040530,11066176,11066475,11066616,11066687,11066968,11067656,11068015,11068296,11067117,11068502,11073105,11072974,11066323,11073725,11074181,11073887,11075345,11076177,11078964,11079912,11084928,11087778,11039361,11089084,11299320,11036144,11093741,11098103,11295667,11106717,11106827,11109834,11110136,11110930,11322598,11111280,11322605,11041358,11111804,11112613,11112565,11326319,11113070,11326484,11326366,11326619,11326643,11326666,11327048,11113786,11329459,11332130,11333713,11332441,11333003,11333272,11334579,11336031,11335364,11336467,11336545,11128981,11136640,11138821,11139903,11151937,11112995,11152470,11162384,11170785,11174996,11175241,11174976,11176703,11176552,11176966,11177172,11067092,11209385,11209705,11210160,11211825}'::integer[])) AND (status = 'a'::"char"))
   Heap Fetches: 31
 Planning time: 1.175 ms
 Execution time: 4.879 ms
(5 rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query can actually be (a bit) improved by using **Evan Carroll's** suggestion.
Rewrite it in the following way:

```
SELECT 
    "messages"."conversation_id"
FROM 
    "messages"
WHERE 
    conversation_id IN
    (
        15934630,
        15934629,
        15388237,
        -- ... about 750 values more...

        11210160,
        11211825
    )
    AND "messages"."status" = '1' ;
```

PostgreSQL will be using **only** `Index Only Scan using index_messages_on_conversation_id_status`, which is about the fastest it can get.

You can have some occasions where the [`Index Only Scan`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html) finds some pages that are not yet fully visible to all transactions (or not known to be), and this means it must recheck the *table data*. When this happens, which is normally for rows recently inserted or updated, the query will take longer.

Compare the two exeuction plans at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=846619e1183e056e9438d19f889fa3f8)*. The difference in timings might not really be representative of your situation, but DBFiddle won't handle 50 M rows.

---

**REMARK**

Your **indexes**, however, show redundancy, and can be improved:

```
messages   | index_messages_on_user_id                     | user_id
messages   | index_messages_on_user_id_and_conversation_id | user_id, conversation_id
```

This pair can be reduced to just the second index. Whenever the database needs to search for a partircular `user_id`, it will already be able to use `index_messages_on_user_id_and_conversation_id` with no (significant) speed difference. Your inserts, updates and deletes will be faster because you're going to have to maintain one less index.

Plus, *depending on how you make your queries*, you could get rid of the first of these two:

```
messages   | index_messages_on_conversation_id        | conversation_id
messages   | index_messages_on_conversation_id_status | status, conversation_id
```

If whenever you look for a `conversation_id` you also look for a `status`, the second index will just do the job. Otherwise, consider whether  `(status, conversation_id)` could be reordered to `(conversation_id, status)` and get rid of the first index. This is not equivalent to the previous index optimization. In this occasion it *might* be useful to have both indexes; but depends on which queries are being done.

Check [Unused Indexes](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index_Maintenance#Unused_Indexes) for further information on how to make sure you don't have more indexes than necessary. Having excess indexes won't harm your `SELECT` performance, but will harm the performance of your manipulations (insert, update, delete).